# Firefox version check shows wrong version

Tags: ubuntu-mate, versions

When I run in the directory where firefox(Ver. 52.5) is located, I get this

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 65.0.1
```

I do have 2 versions, but it should be reporting Ver. 52.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running simply `firefox` from the command line, then you are actually running the 'default' Firefox installation, likely installed and updated by your package manager. You can verify with `which firefox`. You'll probably get `/usr/bin/firefox` which is a link for `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh`. If you have indeed another installation of Firefox, you need to call the executable for this other version. You can do this by doing something similar to `./relative/path/to/this/other/firefox.sh`, or simply going to the folder of this executable and `./firefox`.

Alternatively, you can add this other version to your `$PATH`, but you'll likely want to name it differently than simply `Firefox` to avoid conflicts.